# How to count specific ID's in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, local-storage

I'm writing user shopping cart for my portfolio project. I want to save the IDs of products as well as count of how many specific IDs are in my storage.
I want my data to look like this:

```
[
  {id: '64783', count: '5'},
  {id: '111', count: '50'},
]
```

Since the data is in localStorage I've user JSON parse and stringify, but I do not know how to achieve the data model in LS I've listed above.
Of course i can just store multiple IDs, even when they are the same and then filter it while displaying the shopping cart, but I don't think this is optimal.

```
export const addToCart = (id, userIsLoggedIn) => {
    let cart = [];
    let itemToAdd = {
        id,
        count: 0,
    };
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')){
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        let count = cart.filter(el => el.id === id).length
        console.log(count)
    }
    cart.push(itemToAdd);
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
};
```

I can get the value of count correctly, but my function still appends an entire object instead of updating the count of the item.

How can I solve this?

Comment: try `cart.filter(el => el.id === id).length` since each element is an object with an `id` property

Comment: `cart` is an array and has no property `count`. The objects inside the array have that property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will

1. read the `cart` from `localStorage`
2. check if the id exists in the cart
3. if it does, increment the count
4. otherwise add the item with count:1
5. if the localStorage is empty, it creates the whole object

So, the code is

```
export const addToCart = (id, userIsLoggedIn) => {
    let cart = [];
    let itemToAdd = {
        id,
        count: 1,
    };
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        let item = cart.find(el => el.id === id);
        if (!item) {
            cart.push(itemToAdd);
        } else {
            item.count ++;
        }
    } else {
        cart = [itemToAdd];
    } 
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
};
```

Alternatively

```
export const addToCart = (id, userIsLoggedIn) => {
    let cart = {};
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    }
    cart[id] = (cart[id] || 0) + 1;
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
};
```

In this method the cart contents is like

```
{
    "1111": 2,
    "1234": 1
}
```

etc

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this and edited the original code.
The problem with duplicating results is still present.

Comment: @DanielSkoroś - oh, right - from your code I didn't see that was the problem - so each ID would be only represented once?

Comment: Right now the result looks like this:
[{"id":"5d8b61034a425f055001e9dd","count":0},{"id":"5d8b61034a425f055001e9dd","count":1},{"id":"5d8b61034a425f055001e9dd","count":2},{"id":"5d8b61034a425f055001e9dd","count":3},{"id":"5d8b61034a425f055001e9dd","count":4},{"id":"5d8b61034a425f055001e9dd","count":5},{"id":"5d8b61034a425f055001e9dd","count":6},{"id":"5d8b61034a425f055001e9dd","count":7},{"id":"5d8b61034a425f055001e9dd","count":8}]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you see right now what I want to achieve

Comment: there is a better way, of course ... but that involves changing the object you store in localStorage ... I'll add the code for your consideration